# Why Execute method is not called?

Tags: timer-jobs

I have created custom timer job and successfully deploy it into SP. I see this timer job and feature on the lists. Job is being called every 10 minutes with status "succeeded". Issue is that Execute method is not being called. 
This is part of my code:

```
public override void Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)
    {
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Temp\Timer.txt", "Copy Documents Timer Job Execute: " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\r\n");
    }
```

I'm writing logs to Timer.txt file in constructor too, and constructor code is being executed.
Question: Why Execute method is not being called? What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint timer jobs run in the context of the SharePoint Timer V4 service. Hence, SharePoint will not pick up changes for dll's loaded by this service, unless you either
1. Increment version of your assembly, or
2. Restart SharePoint Timer V4 service

Answer (score 0):

Probably due to the timer process having insuffient rights to write to the directory. The constructor is being called when you create the timer job, which is done with a farm administrator account which is probably a local administrator too (so it does have rights to write).

Check the account the timer service runs under and see if that has sufficient rights to the folder.

Comment: Even when I delete write to file line, rest of code is not being executed. Basically this job is scanning some document libraries to find some documents. So there is not required any extra access level.

Comment: Could you check the ULS logs if there are any errors listed there? Execute is the only thing a job does, so it either works or it doesn't. If it doesn't work there's bound to be something written in the ULS logs.

Comment: This is appearing when job is being executed:
`Site Enumeration Stack:   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBaseCollection.GetEnumerator()    
 at SP2010_CopyDocs.CopyDocsJob.Execute(Guid targetInstanceID)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTimerJobInvokeInternal.Invoke(SPJobDefinition jd, Guid targetInstanceId, Boolean isTimerService, Int32& result)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTimerJobInvoke.Invoke(TimerJobExecuteData& data, Int32& result)`

Comment: Could you attach your debugger to the OWSTIMER process and see if it fires? Make sure you've deployed the correct version of your DLL to the GAC.

Comment: I have added System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); into constructor and Execute method. After deploy job stops in constructor so I can debug, but not in Execute method. This method is not being called.

Comment: restart SharePoint Timer service solved all issues.

Comment: LOL, yeah that's a requirement too ;) Your fresh GAC DLLs won't be loaded untill you restart the timer service.